# My "snake" gets stuck in pygame while trying to move it in a repeating fashion?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been coding for about a year now only using python, and i wanted to test my knowledge by making my first game, so I made snake. Well right now I want the snake to move forward and for the player to be able to move the snake in a direction without stopping it. But I dont know what's wrong with my code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
running = True


x = 0
y = 0
momentum = "null"


def draw_rect(x, y, size, size1):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (204, 65, 242), (x, y, size, size1))

def momentum_forward(x, y):
    while momentum == "a":
        x += -25
    while momentum == "d":
        x += 25
    while momentum == "w":
        x += -25
    while momentum == "s":
        x += 25


while running:

    FPS = 30
    fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 480), 0, 32)
    draw_rect(x, y, 25, 25)


    momentum_forward(x, y)


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x += -25
                momentum = "a"
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x += 25
                momentum = "d"
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                y += -25
                momentum = "w"
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                y += 25
                momentum = "s"


        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You have already a game loop. You don't need the `while` loops in `momentum_forward`:

```py
def momentum_forward(x, y):
    if momentum == "a":
        x += -25
    if momentum == "d":
        x += 25
    if momentum == "w":
        x += -25
    if momentum == "s":
        x += 25
```